# How to constrain my template to only accept lambda with specific input & output type?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++20, c++-concepts

Inspired by other question to calculate taylor series of a function([Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246073/testing-program-for-convergence)), I wrote a template without any constraint to successfully calculate the sum. Here is current code (Template body removed, as @Elliott says it's irrelevant to the point..):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

template<typename ftn>
long double Taylor_sum(ftn terms_to_sum) { /* Summation calculation goes here... */ return result; };

int main(){
    using namespace std; long double x;  cin >> x ;
    long double series_sum = Taylor_sum([x](unsigned long long int i) -> long double { return /*Taylor term here*/; });
    if (!isfinite(series_sum)) cout << "Series does not converge!" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "Series converged, its value is : " << series_sum << endl;
        cout << "Compared to sin                : " << sinl(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

Although the code works enough, to study & practice the `concept` myself, I am trying to constrain the template to accept only lambda with `unsigned long long int` as a input, and `long double` as output. Here is my current attempt (which does not compile):

```
template<typename T,integral ARG>
concept my_lambda = requires(T t, ARG u) {
    { return t(u); };
}

template<my_lambda ftn>
long double Taylor_sum(ftn term) { //The rest is same...
```

I googled various sources, but it seems to me that because the `concept` is relatively new feature in C++20, there seems less material available. Does anyone know how to constrain my template parameter properly?

Comment: For next time, try to make your code examples genuinely [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here the Taylor series is irrelevant to the actual question being asked.

Comment: @Elliott I tried to shorten the code as much as possible.. Maybe the `try-catch` would be removed as it is not much linked to logic, but it shortens only 3 lines.

Comment: It's not a huge deal or anything, but most of your question is just a prelude to the main question. We don't need to know your real-world use-case for syntax you want to make work. Your second lot of code is good enough to show what you want, that you've actually tried to make it work, and where you got stuck.

Comment: @Elliott Well... I am somewhat confused, how much abstraction you wish to have? there are many questions with concrete example with applications, and I suppose this Taylor series example is not much heavy, but practical one.

Comment: @Elliott On second thought, as my original code with usecase example is posted in the linked question, maybe I can safely remove the duplication. So I deleted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to constrain the template to accept only lambda with
> `unsigned long long int` as a input, and `long double` as output.

You can use [compound requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) with *return-type-requirement*:

```
template<typename F>
concept my_lambda = requires(F f, unsigned long long int x) {
    { f(x) } -> std::same_as<long double>;
};

template<my_lambda ftn>
long double Taylor_sum(ftn term) { //The rest is same...
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r8P18nvr7)

Comment: May I extend the question: How do I extend the lambda constrainment to [](std::integral) ->std::floating_point?

Comment: You can do `{ f(x) } -> std::floating_point;`. For the `std::integral` part, I'm afraid there is no simple way.

Comment: Something is not right. `requires(F f, unsigned long long int x)` seems to accept any lambda with numerical type input. (Maybe implicit type conversion is going on?) For example, this `concept` is accepting `[](float x)-> long double` as well.

Comment: Yes, because `unsigned long long int` can be converted to `float`. If you want to define a concept of a lambda that can *only* accept types that satisfies `std::integral`, [this is not what concept is intended to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443702/how-can-unspecified-types-be-used-in-c20-requires-expressions), the compiler can't help you exhaust all types that satisfy `std::integral`.